# Delete with sed characters following certain character

Tags: bash, sed, syntax

I would like to use the command `sed` in Linux to remove everything that follows a character (in the last position) I mean:

imput:

```
/home/directory/hello/world
```

output:

```
/home/directory/hello
```

I would like to get the previous path (as a `cd ..` would do)

Thank you!!

I would like the command sed that does that.

Comment: `dirname /home/directory/hello/world`?

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Why would you invoke `sed` for this?

```
$: p=/home/directory/hello/world
$: echo ${p%/*}
/home/directory/hello
```

If you just *need* to do it that way for some reason...

```
$: sed 's,/[^/]*$,,' <<< /home/directory/hello/world
/home/directory/hello
```